# Preview pricing using Recurly API v3

Tags: php, recurly

Can anyone suggest an approach to get Recurly pricing using its back-end API v3?  There is Recurly.js for front-end pricing and building checkout pages, but we have a need to present pricing to customers prior to purchase (e.g. for quotes), and not necessarily in connection with a checkout flow.  This must be done on the back-end.

We thought about [creating a purchase preview](https://developers.recurly.com/api/v2021-02-25/index.html#operation/preview_purchase) to compute pricing, but this method requires an account code and/or billing information.  For our purposes, pricing is not determined in connection with a specific account, so this doesn't work. The only workaround appears to be to pick an existing account with valid billing information at random and plug that account into the request query. This is really hacky, though.

To summarize, we are trying to compute the price of a subscription with several add-ons that have various pricing tiers using the Recurly API v3 (PHP, in our case), without the need for account or billing info context.  Not looking for a code example here; more focused on the general approach.

Comment: This really depends on how you set up your [plans](https://developers.recurly.com/api/v2021-02-25/index.html#tag/plan) and how you [list them](https://developers.recurly.com/api/v2021-02-25/index.html#operation/list_plans) . I have not done any add-ons in the past but I assume you can list all details of all your plans or [fetch a single plan](https://developers.recurly.com/api/v2021-02-25/index.html#operation/get_plan)

Comment: That said, for development sake, it may be worthwhile to create plans with all add-on configurations (depending on how many you have), that way, all you would need to do is list the plans with their add-ons as opposed to trying to compute the price of a subscription.